# Split .tfrecords file into many .tfrecords files questions

Tags: split, tfrecord

I encountered a problem, when implementing the solution from [Split .tfrecords file into many .tfrecords files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519309/split-tfrecords-file-into-many-tfrecords-files).

#### Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def split_tfrecord(tfrecord_path, split_size):
    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
        ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_path).batch(split_size)
        batch = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        part_num = 0
        while True:
            try:
                records = sess.run(batch)
                part_path = tfrecord_path + '.{:03d}'.format(part_num)
                with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(part_path) as writer:
                    for record in records:
                        writer.write(record)
                part_num += 1
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError: break
split_tfrecord("tf.examples.tfrecord", 20)
```

#### Result:

- I got more than 100+, small `tf_records`, with strange names

```
tf_examples.tfrecord.37040,tf_examples.tfrecord.9984 > tf_examples.tfrecord.37041 tf_examples.tfrecord.99840 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37042 tf_examples.tfrecord.99841 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37043 tf_examples.tfrecord.99842 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37044 tf_examples.tfrecord.99843 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37045 tf_examples.tfrecord.99844 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37046 tf_examples.tfrecord.99845 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37047 tf_examples.tfrecord.99846 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37048 tf_examples.tfrecord.99847 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37049 tf_examples.tfrecord.99848 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.3705 tf_examples.tfrecord.99849 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37050 tf_examples.tfrecord.9985 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37051 tf_examples.tfrecord.99850 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37052 tf_examples.tfrecord.99851 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37053 tf_examples.tfrecord.99852 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37054 tf_examples.tfrecord.99853 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37055 tf_examples.tfrecord.99854 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37056 tf_examples.tfrecord.99855 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37057 tf_examples.tfrecord.99856 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37058 tf_examples.tfrecord.99857 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37059 tf_examples.tfrecord.99858 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.3706 tf_examples.tfrecord.99859 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37060 tf_examples.tfrecord.9986 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37061 tf_examples.tfrecord.99860 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37062 tf_examples.tfrecord.99861 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37063 tf_examples.tfrecord.99862 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37064 tf_examples.tfrecord.99863 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37065 tf_examples.tfrecord.99864 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37066 tf_examples.tfrecord.99865 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37067 tf_examples.tfrecord.99866 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37068 tf_examples.tfrecord.99867 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37069 tf_examples.tfrecord.99868 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.3707 tf_examples.tfrecord.99869 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37070 tf_examples.tfrecord.9987 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37071 tf_examples.tfrecord.99870 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37072 tf_examples.tfrecord.99871 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37073 tf_examples.tfrecord.99872 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37074 tf_examples.tfrecord.99873 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37075 tf_examples.tfrecord.99874 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37076 tf_examples.tfrecord.99875 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37077 tf_examples.tfrecord.99876 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37078 tf_examples.tfrecord.99877 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37079 tf_examples.tfrecord.99878 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.3708 tf_examples.tfrecord.99879 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37080 tf_examples.tfrecord.9988 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37081 tf_examples.tfrecord.99880 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37082 tf_examples.tfrecord.99881 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37083 tf_examples.tfrecord.99882 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37084 tf_examples.tfrecord.99883 >       tf_examples.tfrecord.37085 tf_examples.tfrecord.99884
```

Comment: btw, my tfrecord contains 7900000 lines

Comment: i got 100000 tfrecords not 20

Comment: I little more context would make it easier to understand maybe a more descriptive title.